# Re-Sync with same enodeId

Tags: fast-sync, devp2p

Is there any benefit or detriment to keeping the same endodeId by maintaining the keystore when performing a fresh sync on an otherwise already in sync node?

By maintaining the endodeId does it confuse peers who have seen your node before in a sync'd state? Or does it lower your reputation by suddenly asking for data you should already have? Peers who discovered your enodeId previously don't need to re-learn a new endodeId, could that result in getting peers faster?

I have static-nodes configured and changing enodeId means I have to modify the static-nodes. So which path is more beneficial? Leave the endodeId and start the re-sync, or start fresh with a new enodeId and modify my static-nodes files?

Comment: Since you're using static-nodes.json, are you talking about a PoA clique network? I did lot of resyncs from scratch reusing the same enodeid without any problems. Typically, the other side would have your nodeid in their static-nodes.json, so I am guessing there will be no penalties for request a fresh copy of the chain. However, I am not sure which exact implications it has regarding the reputation.

Comment: For anyone wondering - there doesn't seem to be any downside to keeping the nodekey and maintaining the same enode to reduce the need to update static node configurations. Clients like Nethermind and Open Ethereum make configuring static nodes a breeze.